# Multiple clients on the same domain separated by folder with Apache .htaccess and Zend Framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have a Zend Framework application which is implemented for several clients. Currently each client gets a separate domain with its own SSL certificate. What I'm trying to achieve is to use the same common domain and separate each client's instance of the application by a sub-folder such as below. Each sub-folder contains a completely separate instance of the ZF application. My question is, how can I achieve this with a combination of mod_rewrite, .htaccess and ZF routing in a way that ZF routing won't be affected.

https://www.somedomain.com/client1_app
https://www.somedomain.com/client2_app
https://www.somedomain.com/client3_app

Comment: Can they not use the same app, different database?

Comment: @TimFountain In some cases the apps need specific customization for specific clients.